# C# default keyword vs Default member

Tags: c#, .net

When a struct type provides a Default member that is equivalent to the value provided by the C# default keyword, is there a difference between the two? If there is no difference, is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

For example:

```
System.Reactive.Unit.Default
```

versus

```
default(System.Reactive.Unit)
```

Answer (score 3):

You know what [`default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions) does? It returns the default value of a given type. For reference types like classes this is always `null`.

[`System.Reactive.Unit`](https://github.com/mono/rx/blob/master/Rx/NET/Source/System.Reactive.Core/Reactive/Unit.cs) is a `struct`, hence a value type which is never `null`. In this case `default` returns *"the value produced by setting all value type fields to their default value and all reference type fields to `null`"*.

So yes, in this case it is the same as what the `Default` property returns because the parameterless constructor does the same:

```
static readonly Unit _default = new Unit();

/// <summary>
/// Gets the single unit value.
/// </summary>
public static Unit Default { get { return _default; } }
```

But that's more by accident. Read the documentation first if you don't know what an operator or expression does. Otherwise you can't decide what you need.

Comment: I'm asking specifically about structs where the values are equivalent. If the Default member were not equivalent, there would be an obvious reason for it to exist. Since they are equivalent, there is no obvious reason for the Default member to exist. Is this strictly a stylistic issue, or is there a rationale for or against Default members on value types?